# Continous random variable

Tags: probability

Consider a continuous random variable **X** defined for all real numbers, and its distribution function is continuous and increasing. Let $F (3) = 0. 8$. Is any of the option correct?

1. $f(0. 8) = 3$
2. $F^{-1}(3)=0.8$
3. $F^{-1}(0.8)=-F^{-1}(0.2)$

Is any of those correct? I do not think that the second option is correct following directly from the problem. But what about another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ denote the probability density function and $F(x)$ the cumulative density function. Then,
\begin{align}
F(3) &= 0.8 = P(X \le 3) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^3 f(x) dx
\end{align}
Clearly, 1 is incorrect, as the relationship above does not entail any value for $f(0.8)$.  I don't see also why 2 would be correct.    Now, for 3,
\begin{align}
F^{-1}(0.8) &= 3
\end{align}
but this tells nothing about $F^{-1}(0.2)$.

So, I think none of the options is correct.

Comment: thank you so much